# SQL exp dump file is missing

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, dmp

I am using a batch script to export a .dmp from my database using the 'exp' command.

Everything runs fine and logs correctly (creating a date stamped log file as well) but the .DMP file itself is nowhere to be found. Not in the designated 'FILE="c:/foo/bar.dmp"' location or anywhere else.

The exporter says it has completed correctly with no errors, but alas, no DMP file.

It's not a permissions problem, the same script generates the .log and temporary .txt files fine.

The script is being run on Windows Server 2008, and even running the exp manually through command prompt doesn't create a file, with no errors.

Really stumped on this one. Extremely difficult to diagnose since everything swears blind it worked fine. Hopefully someone has seen something like this before and can help.

Thanks in advance.

Example of script:

```
@echo off
REM setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::Bunch of variable declarations here

echo **Backup run on %DATE% at %TIME%** >> "E:\Backup Logs\FULL_db_%Ffullstamp%_log.txt"
echo **Backing up FULL database** >> "E:\Backup Logs\FULL_db_%Ffullstamp%_log.txt"

exp xxxx/yyyy@zzzz full=Y log="E:\Backup Logs\FULL_TMP.log" file="E:\Backups\FULL\FULL_db_%fullstamp%.dmp"

type "E:\Backup Logs\FULL_TMP.log" >> "E:\Backup Logs\FULL_db_%Ffullstamp%_log.txt"
del "E:\Backup Logs\FULL_TMP.log"
```

I've removed a bit of fluff and identifying parts but that's the bread and butter of it. The TXT and LOG files are being created and deleted perfectly, but no DMP file.

Comment: What does the script look like?

Comment: Presumably this is Oracle not SQL -Server, if so please retag the question.

Comment: Sorry about that, still a bit new to this stuff. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

on windows wouldn't your path require backslashes instead of forward slashes? i.e. `FILE="c:\foo\bar.dmp"'`?

Comment: Batch can handle both forward slashes and backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **expdp** which invokes an export using the Oracle Data Pump utility.
Your data output file will reside in the directory defined by the Oracle parameter DATA_PUMP_DIR.
To find the value of DATA_PUMP_DIR, log into SQL*Plus as 'SYS' and run the following:

```
select * 
from dba_directories 
where DIRECTORY_NAME = 'DATA_PUMP_DIR';
```

Also, be sure that your schema has the **EXP_FULL_DATABASE** role.
The Oracle online documentation can give you further clarification.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/dp_overview.htm#SUTIL100

I would try doing the **expdp** (with the appropriate parameters) from the command-line first to make sure it works.  Then insert the **expdp** command-line into your script.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Though I feel silly.

Having spaces in the 'FILE=' parameter was the issue.

A path of

```
"E:\ClientDocuments\Data Extration\ProgressDump.dmp"
```

Created this

```
"E:\ClientDocuments\Data.dmp"
```

Odd, but very fixable.

Comment: Glad you got your issue solved.  I would recommend you start using Data Pump as an alternative solution and get used to that Oracle Utility.   (From Oracle docs) : Oracle recommends that you use the new Data Pump Export and Import utilities because they support all Oracle Database 10g features, except for XML schemas and XML schema-based tables. Original Export and Import support the full set of Oracle database release 9.2 features. Also, the design of Data Pump Export and Import results in greatly enhanced data movement performance over the original Export and Import utilities.

Comment: @tale852150 Thanks for the advice, I'll update the procedures for next time.

Answer (score 0):

The proper solution is to triple quote your paths, if they contain spaces etc.:

```bat
@Echo Off
Rem SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Bunch of variable declarations here

(   Echo **Backup run on %DATE% at %TIME%**
    Echo **Backing up FULL database**)>>"E:\Backup Logs\FULL_db_%Ffullstamp%_log.txt"

exp xxxx/yyyy@zzzz full=Y log="""E:\Backup Logs\FULL_TMP.log""" file="""E:\Backups\FULL\FULL_db_%fullstamp%.dmp"""

Type "E:\Backup Logs\FULL_TMP.log">>"E:\Backup Logs\FULL_db_%Ffullstamp%_log.txt"
Del "E:\Backup Logs\FULL_TMP.log"
```

This method can be seen within [Chapter 7 of the Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E69230_12/otn/pdf/install/html_agaba/output/chapter_7.htm), *more specifically, 7.3.3.2 Exporting the Full Oracle Database*.